# Twilio gather how can I tell gather wait for sometime before speech starts and start collecting

Tags: python, flask, twilio

SO for accepting incoming call and collecting speech. Here is a sample of the code that I have, using Python and Flask.

```
# more code above
resp.gather(input='speech dtmf', timeout=3, speech_timeout=4, action='/gather', method='POST')
resp.redirect('/gather')

# more code in between

@app.route("/gather", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def gather():
    #print("gather: Entry ")
    resp = VoiceResponse()
    sid = request.form['CallSid']
    SpeechResult = request.values.get("SpeechResult", "")

    params = urllib.parse.urlencode({"SpeechResult": SpeechResult})
    print("0 gather: " + str(params).lower())
```

However, calling this results in:

```
   0 gather: speechresult=
```

When I called the app myself, I noticed it waits for 5 seconds before starting the prompt.  How can I tell gather to start 5 seconds before gather.

I tried adding `time.slpeep(5)` before `resp.gather`... but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I'm not sure what prompt you are talking about here.

What I am missing is that your initial [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) didn't seem to ask for input from the user. This is going to lead to the ~5 seconds of silence while `<Gather>` waits for input then gives up and moves on to the `/gather` endpoint with nothing in the `SpeechResult`.

If you want to say something to user to ask them to respond, you should use a [`<Say>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/say) within your `<Gather>`, like this:

```
gather = resp.gather(input='speech dtmf', timeout=3, speech_timeout=4, action='/gather', method='POST')
gather.say('Please answer the question')
```

You can also use [`<Play>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/play) and [`<Pause>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/pause) within a `<Gather>`.

Let me know if that helps at all.

Comment: In my case, I have an incoming call. Call comes to my Twilio code, my code answers the call, and it expects prompt from the caller.  If the caller is human (me) then the code works fine because I say the prompt and my /gather results what was expected.  However If the caller is a machine which has an original 5 seconds delay before speech begins the gather does not return anything.

Comment: Oh, well I would suggest your system prompts the user rather than the other way around, just as a consideration for user experience. What is the chance of your system receiving incoming calls from machines? Is that an expected use case and what would you expect to do with that sort of call?